# How to implement fromJust and iterate over a list of strings in Haskell

Tags: haskell, option-type, morse-code

So I have got these functions:

```
intercalate' :: [a] -> [[a]] -> [a]
intercalate' xs xss = concat (intersperse' xs xss)

intersperse'             :: a -> [a] -> [a]
intersperse' _   []      = []
intersperse' sep (x:xs)  = x : prependToAll' sep xs

prependToAll'            :: a -> [a] -> [a]
prependToAll' _   []     = []
prependToAll' sep (x:xs) = sep : x : prependToAll' sep xs


encodeWord :: Table -> String -> Maybe Code
encodeWord table str = intercalate' [Silence, Silence]
    <$> mapM (\x -> lookup x table) str
```

for this data:

```
module Types where

data Atom = Beep | Silence
  deriving (Eq, Show)

type Code = [Atom]

dit, dah, shortGap, mediumGap :: Code
dit       = [Beep, Silence]
dah       = [Beep, Beep, Beep, Silence]
shortGap  = replicate (3-1) Silence
mediumGap = replicate (7-1) Silence

morseCode :: Char -> Code
morseCode 'A' = dit ++ dah
morseCode 'B' = dah ++ dit ++ dit ++ dit
morseCode 'C' = dah ++ dit ++ dah ++ dit
morseCode 'D' = dah ++ dit ++ dit
morseCode 'E' = dit
morseCode 'F' = dit ++ dit ++ dah ++ dit
morseCode 'G' = dah ++ dah ++ dit
morseCode 'H' = dit ++ dit ++ dit ++ dit
morseCode 'I' = dit ++ dit
morseCode 'J' = dit ++ dah ++ dah ++ dah
morseCode 'K' = dah ++ dit ++ dah
morseCode 'L' = dit ++ dah ++ dit ++ dit
morseCode 'M' = dah ++ dah
morseCode 'N' = dah ++ dit
morseCode 'O' = dah ++ dah ++ dah
morseCode 'P' = dit ++ dah ++ dah ++ dit
morseCode 'Q' = dah ++ dah ++ dit ++ dah
morseCode 'R' = dit ++ dah ++ dit
morseCode 'S' = dit ++ dit ++ dit
morseCode 'T' = dah
morseCode 'U' = dit ++ dit ++ dah
morseCode 'V' = dit ++ dit ++ dit ++ dah
morseCode 'W' = dit ++ dah ++ dah
morseCode 'X' = dah ++ dit ++ dit ++ dah
morseCode 'Y' = dah ++ dit ++ dah ++ dah
morseCode 'Z' = dah ++ dah ++ dit ++ dit
morseCode '1' = dit ++ dah ++ dah ++ dah ++ dah
morseCode '2' = dit ++ dit ++ dah ++ dah ++ dah
morseCode '3' = dit ++ dit ++ dit ++ dah ++ dah
morseCode '4' = dit ++ dit ++ dit ++ dit ++ dah
morseCode '5' = dit ++ dit ++ dit ++ dit ++ dit
morseCode '6' = dah ++ dit ++ dit ++ dit ++ dit
morseCode '7' = dah ++ dah ++ dit ++ dit ++ dit
morseCode '8' = dah ++ dah ++ dah ++ dit ++ dit
morseCode '9' = dah ++ dah ++ dah ++ dah ++ dit
morseCode '0' = dah ++ dah ++ dah ++ dah ++ dah
morseCode  _  = undefined -- Avoid warnings

type Table = [(Char, Code)]

morseTable :: Table
morseTable = [ (c , morseCode c) | c <- ['A'..'Z']++['0'..'9'] ]
```

The `encodeWord` function works as intended.

Sample: Input: `"HELLO"` Output: `[Beep,Silence,Beep,Silence,Beep,Silence,Beep,Silence,Silence,Silence,Beep,Silence,Silence,Silence,Beep,Silence,Beep,Beep,Beep,Silence,Beep,Silence,Beep,Silence,Silence,Silence,Beep,Silence,Beep,Beep,Beep,Silence,Beep,Silence,Beep,Silence,Silence,Silence,Beep,Beep,Beep,Silence,Beep,Beep,Beep,Silence,Beep,Beep,Beep,Silence]`

Now, I'm trying to define a new function: encodeWords.

Sample: Input: `["HI","THERE"]` Output: `[Beep,Silence,Beep,Silence,Beep,Silence,Beep,Silence,Silence,Silence,Beep,Silence,Beep,Silence,Silence,Silence,Silence,Silence,Silence,Silence,Beep,Beep,Beep,Silence,Silence,Silence,Beep,Silence,Beep,Silence,Beep,Silence,Beep,Silence,Silence,Silence,Beep,Silence,Silence,Silence,Beep,Silence,Beep,Beep,Beep,Silence,Beep,Silence,Silence,Silence,Beep,Silence]`

So far, I have done this.

```
encodeWords :: Table -> [String] -> Maybe Code
encodeWords table stringList = intercalate' [Silence, Silence, Silence,Silence,Silence,Silence]
    <$> mapM (\x -> encodeWord table x ) stringList
```

I was hoping the final function would have the type signature:

```
Table -> [String] -> Code
```

For `encodeWord`, I have only managed to program `Table -> [String] -> Maybe Code`. I've tried using `fromJust` like this:

```
import Data.Maybe    
encodeWord :: Table -> String -> Code
encodeWord table str = fromJust (intercalate' [Silence, Silence]
    <$> mapM (\x -> lookup x table) str)
```

This worked, however, I can only use the Prelude and Data.Char for the program that I am writing.

When I tried:

```
fromJust          :: HasCallStack => Maybe a -> a
fromJust Nothing  = error "Maybe.fromJust: Nothing" -- yuck
fromJust (Just x) = x

type HasCallStack = (?callStack :: CallStack) 

encodeWord :: Table -> String -> Code
encodeWord table str = fromJust (intercalate' [Silence, Silence]
        <$> mapM (\x -> lookup x table) str)
```

I just got this error:

```
   Operator applied to too few arguments: ?
   |
59 | type HasCallStack = (?callStack :: CallStack)
   |                      ^
Failed, one module loaded.
```

Is there an easy way I can implement `fromJust` by myself, just using Data.Char and the Prelude ?

In summary, I'm trying to implement `fromJust` by myself and make this function work:

```
encodeWords :: Table -> [String] -> Maybe Code
encodeWords table stringList = intercalate' [Silence, Silence, Silence,Silence,Silence,Silence]
    <$> mapM (\x -> encodeWord table x ) stringList
```

I'm not sure if I should `Map`, `MapM` or something else to apply `encodeWord` to each of the strings in the list. After that, `encodeWords` should add 6 `Silence`s between the output `Code` for each of the strings in the input list.

Comment: Note that `mapM (\x -> encodeWord table x ) stringList` is the same as `mapM (encodeWord  table) stringList`  (something known as eta-reduction). Did you try something like: `intercalate' Sil6  <$> `(mapM id $ map (encodeWord tb) stringList)`

Comment: "I was hoping the final function would have the type signature: `Table -> [String] -> Code`" Why? This type signature is obviously a lie, because you cannot give me an answer when I ask for `encodeWord "!@#$"`. Better to have your type reflect that fact.

Comment: Incidentally, the error you got about your copy of the definition of `HasCallStack` is due to the fact that `?callStack :: CallStack` isn’t valid syntax unless you enable the `ImplicitParams` extension that it’s using; this expression also has type `Constraint`, so for `type HasCallStack = (?callStack :: CallStack)` to work, I think you must also enable `ConstraintKinds`. Note that this is really an internal implementation detail of the standard `HasCallStack`, which will likely change in the future, so it’s not really the right approach to rely on it anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a perfectly workable error management policy to return `Nothing` if something is wrong, and you can cascade it.

At the very end, you can always put the result thru `fromJust` and suffer the consequences if there is illegal input. As mentioned by HaskellFreak, your version of `fromJust` looks OK.

This code seems to work:

```
myFromJust :: Maybe a -> a
myFromJust  Nothing   =  error "Maybe.fromJust: Nothing" -- yuck
myFromJust  (Just x)  =  x
    
encodeWord :: Table -> String -> Maybe Code
encodeWord table str = (intercalate' [Silence, Silence]
                          <$> mapM (\x -> lookup x table) str)
```

Testing under `ghci`:

```
 λ> 
 λ> encodeWord morseTable "ABC"
Just [Beep,Silence,Beep,Beep,Beep,Silence,Silence,Silence,Beep,Beep,Beep,Silence,Beep,Silence,Beep,Silence,Beep,Silence,Silence,Silence,Beep,Beep,Beep,Silence,Beep,Silence,Beep,Beep,Beep,Silence,Beep,Silence]
 λ> 
 λ> 
 λ> encodeWord morseTable "ABC+"
 Nothing
 λ>
```

Now trying to code the higher level function `encodeWords`:

If we start with just a plain `map` construct:

```
 λ> 
 λ> stringList = ["ATTACK","AT","DAWN"]
 λ> 
 λ> :type (map (encodeWord morseTable) stringList)
 (map (encodeWord morseTable) stringList) :: [Maybe Code]
 λ>
```

So we have a [Maybe Code] object. Given the type signature of `intercalate'`, we would prefer a `Maybe [Code]` one.

```
 λ> 
 λ> :type mapM
mapM :: (Traversable t, Monad m) => (a -> m b) -> t a -> m (t b)
 λ>
```

So if type `a` is the same as `m b`, and the leftmost function parameter is taken to be `id`, we see that `mapM` can swap the list construct with the Maybe one. Like in: `(m b -> m b) -> t (m b) -> m (t b)`.

```
 λ> 
 λ> :type (mapM id)
(mapM id) :: (Traversable t, Monad m) => t (m b) -> m (t b)
 λ> 
 λ> :type (mapM id $ map (encodeWord morseTable) stringList)
 (mapM id $ map (encodeWord morseTable) stringList) :: Maybe [Code]
 λ> 
 λ> 
 λ> sil6 = replicate 6 Silence
 λ> 
 λ> :type  ((intercalate' sil6) <$> mapM id (map (encodeWord morseTable) stringList))
  ((intercalate' sil6) <$> mapM id (map (encodeWord morseTable) stringList))
  :: Maybe [Atom]
 λ>
```

So this can be a valid code for `encodeWords`:

```
encodeWords :: Table -> [String] -> Maybe Code
encodeWords table stringList =
    let  sil6 = replicate 6 Silence
    in
         intercalate' sil6
             <$>  (mapM id  $  map (encodeWord table) stringList)
```

Testing under `ghci`:

```
 λ> 
 λ> length $ myFromJust (encodeWords morseTable stringList)
 112
 λ> (encodeWords morseTable stringList)
 Just [Beep,Silence,Beep,Beep,Beep,Silence,Silence,Silence,Beep,Beep,Beep,Silence,Silence,Silence,Beep,Beep,Beep,Silence,Silence,Silence,Beep,Silence,Beep,Beep,Beep,Silence,Silence,Silence,Beep,Beep,Beep,Silence,Beep,Silence,Beep,Beep,Beep,Silence,Beep,Silence,Silence,Silence,Beep,Beep,Beep,Silence,Beep,Silence,Beep,Beep,Beep,Silence,Silence,Silence,Silence,Silence,Silence,Silence,Beep,Silence,Beep,Beep,Beep,Silence,Silence,Silence,Beep,Beep,Beep,Silence,Silence,Silence,Silence,Silence,Silence,Silence,Beep,Beep,Beep,Silence,Beep,Silence,Beep,Silence,Silence,Silence,Beep,Silence,Beep,Beep,Beep,Silence,Silence,Silence,Beep,Silence,Beep,Beep,Beep,Silence,Beep,Beep,Beep,Silence,Silence,Silence,Beep,Beep,Beep,Silence,Beep,Silence]
 λ>
```

Note that in that context, `mapM id` is the same thing as library function [sequence :: Monad m => t (m a) -> m (t a)](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:sequence), which is definitely in the Prelude set.

In the interest of full disclosure, the Prelude library also includes a [traverse](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=traverse&scope=set%3Astackage) function, which is kind of a dalliance between `sequence` and `map`. So you can write a slightly more elegant version of `encodeWords` like this:

```
encodeWords2 :: Table -> [String] -> Maybe Code
encodeWords2 table stringList =
    let  sil6 = replicate 6 Silence
    in   intercalate' sil6  <$>  traverse (encodeWord table) stringList
```

Answer (score 2):

The definition of `fromJust` you wrote, comes directly out of `Data.Maybe`. This won't work without a simple modification:

```hs
fromJust :: Maybe a -> a
fromJust Nothing = error "fromJust: Nothing"
fromJust (Just x) = x
```

As you can see `fromJust` pattern matches on the constructors of the `Maybe` datatype, like you have done for `morseCode`.

For more information on pattern matching, see: http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions